# Chrome remote desktop breaks MATE desktop on Ubuntu MATE!

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-mate

I’m using Ubuntu MATE 18.04. I’m trying to install chrome remote desktop. I have downloaded a deb file and when I install it, everything is fine until I reboot, but after that when I login, I get an error saying “Could not acquire name on session bus” on a blank black screen. I click “close” woth my mouse pointer and then there is nothing left on the screen except the pointer. I can still open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T. I tried following instructions on the net which advice me to create .chrome-remote-desktop-session file, and edit .profile, and after doing that it still remains the same.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution after searching and experimenting a bit, here it is for people of the future :)

Add these three lines to `.chrome-remote-desktop-session`:

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unset SESSION_MANAGER
mate-session
```

Answer (score 0):

after create `.chrome-remote-desktop-session` file, add next line:

```
exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "keywords=launch;MATE;desktop;session"
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix it.

Chrome remote desktop can cause issues for the gnome-terminal to launch. I uninstalled it using sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop. The terminal launched successfully once I rebooted.